# Change model attribute name

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-8

In my database, the names are in snake case. How can you translate them into a model like CamelCase.

I use

```
public function getAttributes($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations)) {
            return parent::getAttribute($key);
        } else {
            return parent::getAttribute(Str::snake($key));
        }
    }
```

But in dump collection or model I get name in  snake case.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel string helper "camel()" to convert snake case to came case

> use Illuminate\Support\Str;
>
> $converted = Str::of('foo_bar')->camel();
>
> // fooBar

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-camel